# Bootstrap mobile nav displaying as grey line on IOS only

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

When my nav goes into mobile on Android it works perfectly, however on IOS devices it is showing as a faint grey line at the top left.

Any help would be appreciated

http://s671682722.websitehome.co.uk/

Thanks

Comment: make a jsfiddle of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to your css (or scss), seems you don't have a width and chrome fixed it but safari didn't:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    width: 56px;
}
```